# Error when updating state with useState + TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-state

There is a state initialized with an array of objects:

```
interface Product {
  id: number;
  status: boolean;
  color: string;
  price: number;
}

const productList: Product[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    status: true,
    color: 'yellow',
    price: 275
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    status: true,
    color: 'blue',
    price: 325
  }
];

const [products, setProducts] = useState<Product[]>(productList);
```

Only those products are displayed for which the property status == true.
I'm trying to delete a product, so I calculate the new state using the previous state:

```
const productsRender = products.map((product: Product): false | JSX.Element => {
  return(product.status &&
    <ProductWrapper>
      <Product key={product.id}>
        <Remove
          type='button'
          onClick={(): void =>
            //TypeScript error TS2345
            setProducts(prevProducts => [...prevProducts, product.status = false])
          }
        />
        <Color>color: {product.color}</Color>
        <Price>${product.price}</Price>
      </Product>
    </ProductWrapper>
  );
});
```

But I am getting an error:

```
Argument of type '(prevProducts: Product[]) => (boolean | Product)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Product[]>'.
  Type '(prevProducts: Product[]) => (boolean | Product)[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: Product[]) => Product[]'.
    Type '(boolean | Product)[]' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'.
      Type 'boolean | Product' is not assignable to type 'Product'.
        Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Product'.
```

I have tried not passing the function in setProducts:

```
setProducts([...products, product.status = false])
```

But I get TypeScript error TS2322:

```
Type 'boolean | Product' is not assignable to type 'Product'.
  Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Product'.
```

It's not clear to me how to properly update the state.
I would be grateful for help.

Comment: It's not clear what you're hoping to achieve with `setProducts([...products, product.status = false])`, but that tries to put the result of the assignment, `false`, into the array that you told TypeScript would contain `Product`s.

Comment: I need to change the value of the status property from true to false so that the current product is not displayed

Comment: Doesn't that mean updating an existing entry in `products` (which would typically be a `setProducts(products.map(/* ... */))`), rather than adding a new entry to the end of the array (`setProducts([...products, newProduct])`)?

Comment: You can use the `filter` function to return a new array with the product removed, and then set your state to the result of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `...products`, you're referring to the previous products in the array and you're trying to append a `product.status = false` to the array, which is **not** a `Product`.

If you want to update the last value of the products array, you can do this.

```
const productsRender = products.map((product: Product): false | JSX.Element => {
   return(product.status &&
     <ProductWrapper>
       <Product key={product.id}>
         <Remove
           type='button'
           onClick={(): void => {
             let new_products = [...products];
             let atIndex = products.indexOf(product);
             new_products[atIndex].status = false;
             setProducts(new_products);

             // This might work - haven't tested
             //let atIndex = products.indexOf(product);
             //products[atIndex].status = false;
             //setProducts(products);
           }}
         />
         <Color>color: {product.color}</Color>
         <Price>${product.price}</Price>
       </Product>
     </ProductWrapper>
   );
});
```

There might be another way (much prettier).

Comment: I doubt they always want to update the _last_ one, it makes far more sense that they'd be updating the _current_ one (the `product` within the `products.map`).